# Scrape HTML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble scraping content from the following https://pregame.com/game-center/171763/consensus-archive. I'm using Beautiful Soup and only getting back snippets of the HTML, without any of the data that I can clearly see embedded in the code.

This is the latest iteration of code I've used after a handful of attempts (this was an attempt at only grabbing the dates column, but I'm wanting to grab the entire table)...

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://pregame.com/game-center/171763/consensus-archive'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_ = "pg-move-list")
print(results.prettify())
dates = results.find_all("td", class_="pg-col pg-col--date")
for date in dates:
    print(date, end = "\n"*2)
for date in dates:
    data_date = date.find("p", class_= "pg-col-data")
print(data_date.text)
```

The HTML as well...

[image]

Realize there are many similar questions here and elsewhere on the web, but I'm still stuck after referencing them. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: The table data is most likely generated by Javascript. Try using Selenium with Chromedriver or Firefoxdriver to get the rendered page, then scrape that with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is generating dynamically from external source via API. Bs4 can't parse/render JS that's why are grtting static portion of html only.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = 'https://pregame.com/api/gamecenter/consensushistory?e=171763&s=40&r=1000&a=1&c=1&t=693'
r = requests.get(api_url)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['Items'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Id                  DateTime   Odds  ...  IsPickActionChanged  PickAction  PickPercentage
0    60149470   2021-10-17T12:39:05.18Z    +10  ...                False         172              86
1    60147744  2021-10-17T12:16:32.793Z    +10  ...                False         169              86
2    60146757   2021-10-17T12:00:41.64Z    +10  ...                False         162              86
3    60146458  2021-10-17T11:55:49.823Z    +10  ...                False         162              86
4    60146333  2021-10-17T11:53:50.477Z    +10  ...                False         162              86
..        ...                       ...    ...  ...                  ...         ...             ...
130  59716689  2021-10-12T17:41:27.397Z    +10  ...                False          14              82
131  59716636   2021-10-12T17:40:44.01Z    +10  ...                False          14              82
132  59716531  2021-10-12T17:39:28.603Z    +10  ...                False          14              82
133  59715523  2021-10-12T17:24:22.067Z    +10  ...                False          13              81
134  59655757  2021-10-11T01:02:33.873Z  Other  ...                 True           1             100

[135 rows x 12 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful to anyone. Created the following code to access the API using above answer and then loop through a list of URLs.

```
# Read CSV file
URLs = read_csv("URLs_1_250.csv")

# Convert column of URLs to a list
odds = URLs['URL'].tolist()

# Create empty dataframe to append new data to
nfl_data = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through list of urls to scrape odds data
for i in tqdm(range(0,250)):
   url = odds[i]
   r = requests.get(url)
   data = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['Items'])
   nfl_data = nfl_data.append(data, ignore_index = True)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: While posting this as additional answer please check, clean and focus the code(imports), please

Comment: Cleaned up code. Apologies for that.